# Linux: Run cron job in foreground

Tags: linux, cron, foreground

In Linux, is there a way to run a cron job in the foreground (or interactive mode)? (I have a program that runs periodically to accept user input and do some processing. So I want to schedule it as a cron job that can run in the foreground).

Comment: How do you expect `cron` to reach out to you? Opening a terminal, launching a GUI app etc?

Comment: Opening a terminal would work for me. Actually, I do not want to make a sophisticated GUI app. My thought is as follows: If I run the program manually from a shell, I can give input interactively. I want to be able to do the same when the program runs automatically.

Comment: You might perhaps be interested by `expect` http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html but I am not sure it is a good idea to use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this out on your user's `crontab`:

```
@hourly DISPLAY=:0 xterm -e /path/to/my/script.sh
```

It will open (hourly) an `xterm` with your script executing, and exit after your script exits. Of course, you should modify the `@hourly` part to suit your needs.

Answer (score 4):

For `GUI` scripts in `cron`, try the following line in a `shell`:

```
crontab -e
```

Then in `crontab` :

```
0 7 * * * DISPLAY=:0 /PATH/TO/SCRIPT
```

Comment: Adapt it to your needs, for sure ;)

Comment: I tried the same but it still seems to run in the background. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: It worked for me, although I had to restart cron through service cron restart :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are running X, you could always have it open a window on a selected display.

Comment: I am assuming, you mean Mac OS X. I am using Ubuntu. However, I would want my script to work on Ubuntu as well as Mac OS X.

Comment: I meant X windows, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System, and you are probably using it

Comment: Yeah. Guess that's also what the others have suggested. Thanks.

Comment: You should export display variable or add that into your bashrc file

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a GUI and you only have the terminal, divert the exit to tty. Execute ´tty´ and it will return the device to which you will redirect the output. For example, in Centos it will be something like:

```
/ dev / pts / 0
```

Then in `crontab -e` you write:

```
1 * * * * user sh / PATH / TO / SCRIPT> / dev / pts / 0
```

Adjust the time in crontab according to your needs. It will only run if there is someone with that terminal open.

BUT WHAT PEOPLE ARE LOOKING FOR BY THE TITLE OF THE QUESTION:

Linux: Run cron job in foreground

The answer is `nohup command_to_run &`:

```
1 * * * * nohup user sh / PATH / TO / SCRIPT &
```

`nohup` allows executing a script as if it were an open terminal and solves the problem of executing the crontab. I mean when we create a script, for example:

```
#! / bin / bash

echo "I make it up"
```

And we wait for the output of the echo to do something with it. Example:

```
echo "I make it up"
if [[$? -gt 0]]
then
do something with the output of echo
```

The `echo` execution response is obtained through `stdout` in the tty terminal. But from crontab "there is no tty" and a crash occurs and crontab does not execute the application. This is solved with `nohup`. More information: `man nohup`