# Use linux command output in crontab

Tags: linux, cron

I made a shell script and registered to execute every 20 minutes.
Here is my crontab code.

```
*/20 * * * * sh /mypath/run_myprocess.sh &> /dev/pts/34
```

I editted code like this in order to see whether my process run correctly.

I get the result '/dev/pts/34' from tty command in terminal.

However, does anyone know how to use linux command results(in this case: /dev/pts/34)
in crontab? This is because I will use several terminal to run my tasks.

For example, in shell script, I can use linux command result in the form of $(command) such as

```
echo "$(date)"
```

directly.

Plus, if I type something on the terminal during process running with crontab, it actually gives result. For example,

```
Process is running........

ls
backup backup.sh Desktop Task_Folder shared_folder
[UserID] ~ #
```

So I guess cron jobs run correctly but in background.
Please help me to find out how can I bring cron jobs in foreground.

Comment: `echo "$(date)"` seems completely redundant. Just use `date` directly. ;)

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771333/linux-run-cron-job-in-foreground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start a job on your console and background it you can then bring it to foreground. If the task is not yours or not started on your terminal then you can not.