# Python user input when scheduled with cron

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi

I'm creating an alarm clock with my Raspberry Pi.

The idea is that to disable the alarm clock - I have to enter a randomly generated sequence of numbers.

How do I schedule this python script to run via cron that allows user input from the keyboard?

Or if it's not possible - how would I go about creating an application in general terms that can run at a set time, and take user input?

This Raspberry Pi is running headless and my app speaks the numbers out loud but I've skipped it here for simplicity.

```
import random

s = str(random.randint(10, 99))

print s

while True:
    question = raw_input("Enter code as above: ")
    if question == s:
        print "Alarm Disabled"
        break
    else:
        print "Wrong Code. Try Again"
```

And here's the cronjob to run Monday to Friday at 7:30am:

`crontab -e 30 7 * * 1-5 sudo python /home/pi/alarmclock.py`

**EDIT: OK I have a work around:**

If I run the Rasberry Pi with a GUI:

`startx`

install "xterm" and change my crontab to:

`crontab -e 30 7 * * 1-5 DISPLAY=:0 xterm -e /usr/bin/python /home/pi/alarmclock.py`

It works. I was just hoping I could launch it with without running X (Could be an issue of application focus and my text doesn't get entered in the right window)

Which I got from: [Linux: Run cron job in foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771333/linux-run-cron-job-in-foreground)

Comment: maybe run it using subprocess and open a shell

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what the "terminal" is to load when using subprocess when I've just got the console open. I have figured out a work around which I've posted above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a named pipe. To create it, run `mkfifo /home/pi/pipe`. Change the crontab invocation: `python /home/pi/alarmclock.py </home/pi/pipe`.

To input the code, run:

```
$ cat >/home/pi/pipe
Enter the code here and press Enter
Press Ctrl-D to signal EOF
```

Though it allows to enter the input asynchronously that might defeat the purpose of an alarm clock.