# AWS log driver not picking up `tail -f` to Docker image `stdout`

Tags: docker, cron, aws-cloudformation, alpine-linux, aws-fargate

I have an Alpine Docker image I'm deploying using Fargate. This is the command it runs:

```
crond -d 8 && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

I'm writing to the file by appending `>> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1` to the cron job definition. When I run `docker-compose up`, I see all the logs in Docker's output, so I know the logging is working within the container.

I have this as part of my container definition in my CloudFormation template:

```
LogConfiguration:
  LogDriver: awslogs
  Options:
    awslogs-region: "us-east-1"
    awslogs-group: !Ref AvRcloneLogGroup
    awslogs-stream-prefix: "av-rclone"
```

When I was experimenting with my Docker command, I got some logs into CloudWatch by running `crond` in foreground with debug logs to `stdout`, so I know the AWS log driver is working.

However, when I try to switch to `tail -f` to output the job logs to the logs driver, nothing shows up in the console.

How can I get the AWS log driver to pick up these logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution with help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63309380/937377) to a similar question, though I'm still unsure why `tail -f` wasn't working for me.

In order to ensure that Fargate instantiates the image with a virtual terminal, I added this line to the `ContainerDefinition` inside my `TaskDefinition` in my CloudFormation template:

```
PseudoTerminal: true
```

I then changed the Dockerfile `CMD` to this:

```
CMD tty; crond -f
```

The `-f` option tells `crond` to run in the foreground, preventing the image from exiting prematurely.

Including `tty` is not strictly necessary, but was how I found the file name of the virtual terminal. In my case, the output was this:

```
/dev/pts/0
```

Instead of appending output from my cron job to a log file, I redirected it to the virtual terminal by appending this to the end of each job definition:

```
> /dev/pts/0 2>&1
```

And that's it. Now output from my jobs is piped to the virtual terminal, which ends up in my CloudWatch group.